# How to parse value from database datareader and handle possible NULL value?

Tags: c#, vb.net, null, types

I have run into this problem a few times and have never come up with a good answer. I figure others must have dealt with this already.

I have a datareader returned from the database and I want to use the values therein however values may or may not contain NULL. I would like to have a helper function that takes in the value from the datareader and returns the value if it is not NULL and blank space if it is NULL.

The problem I have is that the data-type of the variable I am testing is variable. It can be a String, and Integer or a DateTime. Can anyone suggest a simple way to test the value and then return the original value (as same data-type if possible) or something else if it is NULL?

I am using VB.NET at the moment but I would also like to know how to do this in C#. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for most things I believe (I've not tested it mind):

```
 public T ParseValue<T>(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader, string column)
 {
     T result = default(T);

     if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(column)))
         result = (T)reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(column));

     return result;
 }
```

And will return you the default value for that type if it is `null`

Comment: I like this. Simple yet effective. Now I just need to convert it to VB.NET.

Comment: @webworm Excellent, let me know how you get on with it. Also note the update I've just made, I've simplified it slightly and fixed an error with checking if its null (I'd been using a custom reader that lets you check if a columns null by the name, but the SqlDataReader needs an index)

Answer (score 2):

```
int v = dr.GetValue<int>("vvv");             // throws if column is null
int? w = dr.GetValue<int?>("www");           // set to null if column is null
int x = dr.GetValue<int?>("xxx") ?? -1;      // set to -1 if column is null
string y = dr.GetValue<string>("yyy");       // set to null if column is null
string z = dr.GetValue<string>("zzz") ?? ""  // set to "" if column is null

// ...

public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataRecord source, string fieldName)
{
    return source.GetValue<T>(source.GetOrdinal(fieldName));
}

public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataRecord source, int fieldIndex)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    if (fieldIndex < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fieldIndex", fieldIndex,
                                              "Index cannot be negative.");

    if (source.IsDBNull(fieldIndex))
    {
        T defaultValue = default(T);
        if (defaultValue == null)
            return defaultValue;
    }

    // throws if the field is null and T is a non-nullable value type
    return (T)source.GetValue(fieldIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use an extension method that takes an object, the expected/final type and the default value. If the object is null (or DBNull) it returns the default value. If the object can be converted to the final/expected type it does the conversion and returns a strongly typed object. If the conversion fails it returns a default value or throws an exception based upon if you are strict or not. Here is what the method looks like -

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the non null value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="item">The item.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value.</param>
    /// <param name="strict">if set to <c>true</c> [strict].</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static T GetNonNullValue<T>(this object item, T defaultValue, bool strict) {
        if(item.IsNullOrEmpty() || item == DBNull.Value) {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        var originalType = item.GetType();
        var targetType = typeof(T);

        if(originalType == targetType || originalType.IsSubclassOf(targetType)) {
            return (T)item;
        }

        TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
        if(typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(originalType)) {
            return (T)typeConverter.ConvertFrom(item);
        }

        typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(originalType);
        if(typeConverter.CanConvertTo(targetType)) {
            return (T)typeConverter.ConvertTo(item, targetType);
        }

        if(strict) {
            throw new QIGException("Conversion from {0} to {1} failed!", originalType, targetType);
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
```

Edit1:
To clarify, you'll use this with your data reader like this -

```
        SqlDataReader dr = GetResultsIntoDataReader();
        string column1Value = dr["ColumnName1"].GetNonNullValue(String.Empty);
        int? column2Value = dr["ColumnName2"].GetNonNullValue(new Nullable<int>());
        double column3Value = dr["ColumnName3"].GetNonNullValue(0.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that w69rdy's answer did not work for SQL Money type or Numeric.  I tried using it to convert Money to float and double.  Neither worked.  I converted my Money type to Numeric (18,4) and still it would not convert to float or double.

In all cases it threw a type cast exception.

I did however get YetAnotherUser's answer to work with a couple minor changes.

Had to change:

```
if(item.IsNullOrEmpty() || item == DBNull.Value)
```

to

```
if(item == null || item == DBNull.Value) **
```

AND

throw new QIGException("Conversion from {0} to {1} failed!", originalType, targetType);

to

```
throw new Exception(string.Format("Conversion from {0} to {1} failed!", originalType, targetType));
```

Also added:

```
public static T GetNonNullValue<T>(this object item, T defaultValue)
{
    return item.GetNonNullValue(defaultValue, true);
}
```

so the call could be:

```
curInsurance.Pharmacy = dataReader["Pharmacy"].GetNonNullValue(-1d);
```

NOT

```
curInsurance.Pharmacy = dataReader["Pharmacy"].GetNonNullValue(-1d, true);
```

Also I had to read about Custom Extension, but man are they cool.  I am going to have to explore them some more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IDataReader.IsDBNull` method to check if a field is NULL in the database.